# Use regex to analyze path in Makefile

Tags: regex, makefile, filepath

I need to do some replacement of the path in Makefile.
For example, I have a path like this

p := some/path/to/file

I would like to do the replacement of "p" to get this

../../../file

In other words, I'd like to replace the path to relative path. How can I use regex to do that in Makefile? Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you not use something along the lines of `p := ../../../$(notdir $(p))`?

Comment: @Kavanai4 no. The path level is uncertain. maybe p = some/other/path/to/file. say, ../../../../file

Comment: Do you need to replace the text in path to '..'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on software/language you are using to edit just replace any word ending with "/" to ".../"

This way you will get your relative path. Live demo [here.](https://regex101.com/r/iS7sH3/1)

For special characters you can wrap everything in `[]` and add special characters you are expecting, for example like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iS7sH3/3). Some need escaping with `\`, just give it a try on [Regex101](http://regex101.com) to find out which ones.
If you also have digits in your filepath you need to add `\d` to the "pool": [demo.](https://regex101.com/r/iS7sH3/4)

Comment: You cant use regular expressions in a `makefile`. This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Kavanai4 Isn't makefile a textfile which as such can be edited? If so, why can't you use a regex for it?

Comment: @Asunez Thanks for your answer. One more question. If the path contains some special char, how can we deal with it? For example, p = so_me/pa-th/to/file